# Hot water shut off both valves

Tags: water-tank

There are two shut off valves on my hot water heater. It's leaking from the bottom of the tank.  One is coming out of the bottom of the tank and the other is coming out the top of the tank... Do I shut off both valves on it??

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, bottom is cold, top is hot (because heat rises). So close the bottom, then turn on your hot water faucets - ideally including at least one that is below the height of the tank. Do not turn on any mixing faucets (e.g., a single-handle faucet or a shower with an anti-scald mixer). Once the faucets stop running, close the top valve.

If the heater is electric, turn off the circuit breaker.

If the heater is gas, turn off the gas valve.

Comment: Then get someone in to fix it. <- that _should_ be obvious, but just in case...